# Move application to background

Tags: tizen, android-homebutton, home-button

Similar to `Android` and `Ios`  I want to move my application to background and move foreground without losing progress on opening again. How can we achieve that in `Tizen`. The hardware `home` button is doing the same how can I do that through code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
Tizen::App::UiApp::GetInstance()->GetAppFrame()->GetFrame()->SetShowState(false);
```

Edited:

You can reenable the form by placing the following code in your app's OnBackground():

```
Tizen::App::UiApp::GetInstance()->GetAppFrame()->GetFrame()->SetShowState(true);
Tizen::App::UiApp::GetInstance()->GetAppFrame()->GetFrame()->Show();
```

Comment: Once you set the showstate false , it will suddenly call onBackground .is nt it?

Comment: When you set ShowState to false, your app goes to the background. The platform gets control. Then OnBackground() event is called. Your app is not going to be shown even if you call SetShowStatus(true) and Show() because it's already on the background state. If you tap your app's icon on the home menu then your app is coming to the foreground. I have confirmed this way worked on my device.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by making the home app to the foreground. e.g. on the emulator:

```
Tizen::App::AppManager::GetInstance()->LaunchApplication("org.tizen.menu-screen");
```

A problem is that the app id of the home app may vary each device. I have a dev phone which has 'com.samsung.cluster-home' as a home app. If we got other devices from other vendors, they may have different home apps.

Comment: So then how can we specify it? commonly for all phones

Comment: You might be using `Tizen::App::Package::PackageManager::GetInstance()->GetPackageAppInfoListN()` to find which app is the home app. On my device it's retured 3 apps though...

Answer (score 0):

Since 2.1 you can do as following:

```
Tizen::App::UiApp::GetInstance()->GetAppFrame()->GetFrame()->SetShowMode(Tizen::Ui::Controls::FRAME_SHOW_MODE_MINIMIZED);
```

After this call OS sends application's active frame to the background and calls Tizen::App::UiApp::OnBackground() handler.